# How could an ASP.NET application enforce HTTPS on a per-API basis?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a curiosity question re: HTTP and HTTPS and ASP.NET applications.

Consider a scenario where a service accepts both HTTP and HTTPS requests for APIs in the same basepath - for instance:
http://renandstimpy.com/happy/insecure-joy
https://renandstimpy.com/happy/secure-joy

Now, let's say I wanted to ensure someone couldn't call the secure-joy API via *http*://renandstimpy.com/happy.
How could an ASP.NET application enforce HTTPS on a per-API basis?

Comment: Are you using a particular framework? In Web API the `[RequireHttps]` attribute  on a controller method does that.

Comment: Why you dont the URi and redirect it to https in case request came from http

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than a few options:

1. above answer `UrlRewrite`
2. above comment [`RequireHttps` Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.requirehttpsattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)
3. Create a [`Filter`](https://benjii.me/2015/10/redirect-to-https-asp-net-mvc/) that you can apply as needed (not necessarily entire site)
4. Check for [`HttpRequest.IsSecureConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.issecureconnection?view=netframework-4.8) as needed and do whatever you want

### Caveat:

You must be familiar with your hosting environment. Example, your host employs a load balancer and front-ends SSL requests, then only `UrlRewrite` will work - because the traffic between load balancer and your host(s) will *always* be `http`, not `https`. `https` traffic is between clients and the load balancer. Trying to detect secure connection *in your app* in this case will always be `false` - which likely results in an (endless) redirect loop error.

Your hosting provider should provide guidance on this - usually via info in forwarded `http` `headers`. If provided, then `Filters` would also be an option (by inspecting said `http` `headers`).

Comment: "traffic between load balancer and your host(s) will always be http" - not necessarily. We use HTTPS between our load balancer and web servers so that we don't have unencrypted data flowing across our network. But your other advice still is solid.

Comment: @mason Cool beans. The gist essentially goes back to knowing how your site is hosted. Depending on host provider, such details could be "lost in the weeds" (you'll have to dig for it).

Answer (score 3):

In IIS I use UrlRewrite to redirect all requests to HTTPS. You should be able to use the matching conditions to exclude various URLs and only redirect to HTTPS for the ones you want.

EDIT: Did a quick test and this seems to work...
[image: Url Rewrite Matching Condition Diaglog]

Answer (score 0):

You can detect URL in global.asx & redirect it. if i understood your requirement

```
 void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String checkURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
        string newURL = string.Empty;


        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("http://renandstimpy.com/happy/insecure-joy") )
        {
            newURL = "https://renandstimpy.com/happy/secure-joy";

            HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectPermanent(newURL); //301 redirect
            // HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(newURL);
        }

}
```